# Set bar button item as back button on navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have 3 view controllers, and the initial one is embedded in a navigation controller. On my second view controller, I hide the navigation bar, and I have a custom back button that I would like to use to go back to the previous page.

This is my back button on the toolbar.

```
@IBOutlet var backButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

This is the function for the back button

```
@IBAction func exitEditor(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.popItem(animated: true)
}
```

When I test it out, I get this error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot call popNavigationItemAnimated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'

Comment: Simply replace this line - navigationController?.navigationBar.popItem(animated: true) with this -
 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) . Your code will run like a charm ;)

Comment: But, here, My ViewController getting poped. But, NavigationBar still remains the last page. For Eg: From Page 3, I am calling ur code, Page 2 is visible, but navigation bar is still showing Page 3 as Title

Comment: @AmirKhan , Can u guide me pls?

Comment: @McDonal_11 hi, have you solved the bug yet?

Comment: No, I couldn't., Can u guide me?

Comment: yeah sure @McDonal_11, tell me what issue you are getting now?

Comment: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot call popNavigationItemAnimated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.' This error I am receiving .

Comment: Scenario:

In **shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest,** , I am checking with if condition, that, if (request.url?.absoluteString.contains("nativeback:"))!

Comment: If yes, **self.navigationController?.navigationBar.popItem(animated: true)**, but this is not working. Error: **WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> Cannot call popNavigationItemAnimated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.**

Comment: I am, using UIWebView.

Comment: @McDonal_11 do two stuffs before popping `stop loading request` & `set nil to webView delegate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192258/discussion-between-amir-khan-and-mcdonal-11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func exitEditor(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This is how you pop the current viewController from navigation stack.

Comment: But, here, My ViewController getting poped. But, NavigationBar still remains the last page. For Eg: From Page 3, I am calling ur code, Page 2 is visible, but navigation bar is still showing Page 3 as Title.